# Insert into table, return id and then insert into another table with stored id

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, sql-insert

I have the following three tables:
Please note that the below DDL came models generated by Django then grabbed out of Postgresql after they were created. So modifying the tables is not an option.

```
CREATE TABLE "parentTeacherCon_grade"
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "currentGrade" VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "parentTeacherCon_parent"
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    grade_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "parentTeacherCon_teacher"
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade"
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    teacher_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    grade_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE "parentTeacherCon_parent" ADD FOREIGN KEY (grade_id) REFERENCES "parentTeacherCon_grade" (id);
CREATE INDEX "parentTeacherCon_parent_5c853be8" ON "parentTeacherCon_parent" (grade_id);
CREATE INDEX "parentTeacherCon_teacher_5c853be8" ON "parentTeacherCon_teacher" (grade_id);
ALTER TABLE "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade" ADD FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES "parentTeacherCon_teacher" (id);
ALTER TABLE "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade" ADD FOREIGN KEY (grade_id) REFERENCES "parentTeacherCon_grade" (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade_teacher_id_20e07c38_uniq" ON "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade" (teacher_id, grade_id);
CREATE INDEX "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade_d9614d40" ON "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade" (teacher_id);
CREATE INDEX "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade_5c853be8" ON "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade" (grade_id);
```

My Question is: How do I write an insert statement (or statements) where I do not have keep track of the IDs? More specifically I have a teacher table, where teachers can teach relate to more than one grade and I am attempting to write my insert statements to start populating my DB. Such that I am only declaring a teacher's name, and grades they relate to.

For example, if I have a teacher that belong to only one grade then the insert statement looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO "parentTeacherCon_teacher" (name, grade_id) VALUES ('foo bar', 1  );
```

Where grades K-12 are enumerated 0,12

But Need to do something like (I realize this does not work)

```
INSERT INTO "parentTeacherCon_teacher" (name, grade_id) VALUES ('foo bar', (0,1,3)  );
```

To indicate that this teacher relates to K, 1, and 3 grades

leaving me with this table for the parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | teacher_id | grade_id |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 |          3 |        0 |
|  2 |          3 |        1 |
|  3 |          3 |        3 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

This is how I can currently (successfully) insert into the Teacher Table.

```
INSERT INTO public."parentTeacherCon_teacher" (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Foo Bar');
```

Then into the grade table

```
INSERT INTO public.parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade (id, teacher_id, grade_id) VALUES (1, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO public.parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade (id, teacher_id, grade_id) VALUES (2, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO public.parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade (id, teacher_id, grade_id) VALUES (3, 3, 3);
```

A bit more information. 
[Here is a diagram of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j73la.jpg)

Other things I have tried.

```
WITH i1 AS (INSERT INTO "parentTeacherCon_teacher" (name) VALUES ('foo bar')
RETURNING id) INSERT INTO "parentTeacherCon_teacher_grade"
  SELECT
    i1.id
    , v.val
  FROM i1, (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) v(val);
```

Then I get this error.

```
[2016-08-10 16:07:46] [23502] ERROR: null value in column "grade_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Detail: Failing row contains (6, 1, null).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the same statement? Use stored functions to perform the complex data manipulations.

Comment: Because I do not know the id of the teacher when I insert. I do not want to keep track of them.

Comment: @GordanLinoff Updated with "My question" above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert all three rows in one statement, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO "parentTeacherCon_teacher" (name, grade_id) 
    SELECT 'foo bar', g.grade_id
    FROM (SELECT 0 as grade_id UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3) g;
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
INSERT INTO "parentTeacherCon_teacher" (name, grade_id) 
    SELECT 'foo bar', g.grade_id
    FROM (VALUES (0), (2), (3)) g(grade_id);
```

EDIT:

In Postgres, you can have data modification statements as a CTE:

```
WITH i as (
      INSERT INTO public."parentTeacherCon_teacher" (id, name)
          VALUES (3, 'Foo Bar')
          RETURNING *
     )
INSERT INTO "parentTeacherCon_teacher" (name, teacher_id, grade_id) 
    SELECT 'foo bar', i.id, g.grade_id
    FROM (VALUES (0), (2), (3)) g(grade_id) CROSS JOIN
         i
```

Comment: This does not work if 'foo bar' has not been added yet. I want to be able to add both a new teacher and the grades at the same time.